# SQLAlchemy Declarative - schemas in SQL Server and foreign/primary keys

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm struggling to create tables that belong to a schema in a SQL Server database, and ensuring that primary/foreign keys work correctly.

I'm looking for some examples of code to illustrate how this is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ingredients needed for this are `__table_args__` and the use of the schema prefix on the  `ForeignKey`

```
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    __table_args__ = {"schema": 'my_schema'}

    id = Column(Integer,primary_key = True)
    col1 = Column(String(150))
    col2 = Column(String(100))

    reviews = relationship("Table2", cascade = "delete")  

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    __table_args__ = {"schema": 'my_schema'}

    id = Column(Integer,primary_key = True)
    key = Column(Integer)
    col2 = Column(String(100))



    key = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("my_schema.table1.id"), index=True)  
    premise = relationship("Table1") 


Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Comment: This did not work for me with sqlalchemy.__version__ == '1.4.22' and MS SQL 2014. As a workaround, after the tables were created in the db, I executed `ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER yourschema.Table1` (replace with your schema and table). SQL Alchemy did not complain about it.