# sqlalchemy map table from mssql database with "prefix-namespaces"

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, orm, sqlalchemy

I have been struggling on this for a while now and did not find an answer yet, or maybe I already have seen the answer and just didnt get it - however, I hope I am able to describe my problem.

I have a MS SQL database in which the tables are grouped in namespaces (or whatever it is called), denoted by Prefix.Tablename (with a dot). So a native sql statement to request some content looks like this:

```
    SELECT TOP 100 
     [Value], [ValueDate]
    FROM [FinancialDataBase].[Reporting].[IndexedElements]
```

How to map this to sqlalchemy?
If the "Reporting" prefix would not be there, the solution (or one way to do it) looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

def get_session():
    from urllib.parse import quote_plus as urllib_quote_plus

    server = "FinancialDataBase.sql.local"
    connstr = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=FinancialDataBase" % server
    params = urllib_quote_plus(connstr)
    base_url = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params

    engine  = create_engine(base_url,echo=True)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    return engine, session

Base = declarative_base()

class IndexedElements(Base):
    __tablename__ = "IndexedElements"

    UniqueID = Column(String,primary_key=True)
    ValueDate = Column(DateTime)
    Value = Column(Float)
```

And then requests can be done and wrapped in a Pandas dataframe for example like this:

```
import pandas as pd

engine, session = get_session()

query = session.query(IndexedElements.Value,IndexedElements.ValueDate)

data = pd.read_sql(query.statement,query.session.bind)
```

But the SQL statement that is compiled and actually executed in this, includes this wrong FROM part:

```
FROM [FinancialDataBase].[IndexedElements]
```

Due to the namespace-prefix it would have to be

```
FROM [FinancialDataBase].[Reporting].[IndexedElements]
```

Simply expanding the table name to

```
__tablename__ = "Reporting.IndexedElements"
```

doesnt fix it, because it changes the compiled sql statement to

```
FROM [FinancialDataBase].[Reporting.IndexedElements]
```

which doesnt work properly.

So how can this be solved?

Comment: The term you're looking for is [schema](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx). SQLAlchemy supports schemas both in the [metadata](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.params.schema) as the default schema to use and [per table](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.schema). With Declarative you should pass a per table schema in the [`__table_args__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#table-configuration).

Comment: Very much related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538132/sqlalchemy-declarative-schemas-in-sql-server-and-foreign-primary-keys

Comment: Thanks Ilja, "schema" nailed it! I will create an answer referring to your comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is given in the comment by Ilja above:

The "namespace" is a so called schema and has to be declarated in the mapped object. Given the example from the opening post, the mapped table has to be defined like this:

```
class IndexedElements(Base):
    __tablename__ = "IndexedElements"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "Reporting"}

    UniqueID = Column(String,primary_key=True)
    ValueDate = Column(DateTime)
    Value = Column(Float)
```

Or define a base class containing these informations for different schemata. Check also "Augmenting the base" in sqlalchemy docs:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#augmenting-the-base