# join on two different databases with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Im trying to make a join on 2 databases in MSSQL.

here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT od.Indice, cs.Argued
FROM HN_Ondata.dbo.ODCalls as od
JOIN HN_ADMIN.dbo.CallStatus as cs ON od.CallStatusGroup = cs.StatusGroup
```

I have tried:

- create two engines making the tables with autoload and query it.
- create two engines opening two session and making a subquery.
- create two engines create a CTE of table2.
- create a metadata bind to database1 reflect table1 then call reflect(bind=database2) for table2

always end up with this error:

```
pymssql.ProgrammingError: (208, b"Invalid object name 'CallStatus'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

The current solution i got is using session.execute and write down raw sql, i could stick with it but im currious is there any way doing that with sqlalchemy ORM ?

EDIT 1:

Here is my code :

```
 db1 = DatabaseManager(settings.DATABASE['hrm'], database='HN_Ondata')
 db2 = DatabaseManager(settings.DATABASE['hrm'], database='HN_ADMIN')

 metadata1 = MetaData(bind=db1.database)
 metadata2 = MetaData(bind=db2.database)

 table1 = Table('ODCalls', metadata1, autoload=True)
 table2 = Table('CallStatus', metadata2, autoload=True)


 with db1.session(raise_err=True) as session:
     result = (
         session
         .query(table1.c.Indice, table2.c.Argued)
         .join(table2, table1.c.CallStatusGroup == table2.c.StatusGroup)
         .all()
     )
```

who produce the following query:

```
SELECT [ODCalls].[Indice] AS [ODCalls_Indice], [CallStatus].[Argued] AS [CallStatus_Argued] 
FROM [ODCalls]
JOIN [CallStatus] ON [ODCalls].[CallStatusGroup] = [CallStatus].[StatusGroup]
```

Comment: Are the databases on the same server?

Comment: Yes they are on same server

Comment: in that case its possible the names aren't right. Copy and paste the full table link exactly. Or you might also need to clarify the server e.g (s1.db1.dbo.t1) for both

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a cross-database-query join in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590982/how-to-do-a-cross-database-query-join-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: @RyanGadsdon not sure where i should clarify the server, i had my code in answer

Comment: @IljaEverilä same probleme but solution does not work for me because i dont hardcode the table, i use autoload to reflect it, i have tried to specify db1.dbo.table in the Table args but does not work

Comment: Good point, retracted close vote. Reflection example of the same is a good addition to the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution thank's to Ryan Gadsdon and Ilja Everilä pointing me the way.

You need to precise database.schema in Table schema parameters like this:

```
table1 = Table('ODCalls', metadata1, autoload=True, schema='HN_Odcalls.dbo')
```

Specify Database in schema is needed only if the table refer to a database who your engine is not connected, if you precise database.schema in schema parameters you can then use the table with any engine connected to any database on the same server.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#multipart-schema-names