# Analyse Data within multiple tables between two SQL Databases using Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, data-analysis

I have been given two SQL Databases which are of same schema type but differ by table names or columns names within those tables.

I am required to analyse those data within the tables and suggest , which are the similar(based on data within the table) tables between those two databases.

Can anybody suggest me to how to move forward with this problem statement.
I am new to Data Analytics using Python.
It will be really helpful if someone can help me with this.

As an example : lets Consider two databases A and B . . . 
A contains a table called "person_details" and
B contains a table called "details"

I am looking for answers where i can recomend by analyzing the data within those two tables that they can be joined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590982/how-to-do-a-cross-database-query-join-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using sqlite package of python for connecting to db and querying in it. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Via query you can check the schema of tables. Or if you want to analyse data using pandas then consider using SQLAlchemy for creating connection to DB. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#supported-databases

After that read tables as pandas DataFrame using this
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_sql_table.html

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    import pandas as pd

    engine_A = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_A.db')
    engine_B = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_B.db')

    data_A = pd.read_sql_table("person_details",engine_A)
    data_B = pd.read_sql_table("details",engine_B)
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Any techniques that you can suggest to compare data between those tables ? I mean recommending that those tables contain similar kind of data within those tables. For example lets assume person_details has a row with "abc" "24" "country" and details has a row with "def" "21" "country". Now, how can i analyse this. any suggestions?

Comment: You can compare unique values of the categorical columns. This is one of the idea you could use. Doing analysis on the data is much broader which cannot be solved in one line.

        data_A.column_name.value_counts()