# How to join 2 tables from 2 different database MSSQL in Fastapi & SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, join, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have 2 class as follow:

```
class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Model'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'Smart_Tooling_Platform_Test.dbo'}

    factory_id = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
    model_no = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
    model_name = Column(String, index=True)
    model_type_id = Column(String, index=True)
    model_family = Column(String, index=True, default="")
    upper_id = Column(String, index=True)
    dev_season = Column(String, index=True)
    prod_season = Column(String, index=True)
    volume = Column(Float, default=None)
    volume_percent = Column(Float, default=None)
    remarks = Column(String, default="")
    model_picture = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean)
    top_model = Column(Boolean)
    pilot_line = Column(Boolean)
    create_by = Column(String)
    create_time = Column(DateTime)
    update_by = Column(String)
    update_time = Column(DateTime)


class Type(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Type"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'ChamCongDungB1.dbo'}
    factory_id = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
    model_type_id = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
    model_type_name = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean)
```

These 2 classes are located in 2 different MSSQL databases. Now i want to write a query to join these 2 tables according to 2 columns model_type_id and factory_id using SqlAlchemy in Fastapi. I have tried many ways but no success. Everyone please help.

I try that:

```
    async def get_data_from_2_db(self, model_param):
        query = self.session.query(Model, Type).join(Type, and_(Model.model_type_id == Type.model_type_id,
                                                                Model.factory_id == Type.factory_id)).all()
        return query
```

but have something wrong

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]無效的物件名稱 'ChamCongDungB1.dbo.Type'。 (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that schemas come from different data tables using the `__table_args` attribute
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590982/how-to-do-a-cross-database-query-join-in-sqlalchemy) here maybe helps.