# Unwanted square brackets inserted in SQL statement from ORM

Tags: sql-server, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a simple select on my table mapped with sqlalchemy but I can't get it to match the exact table name.

As I noticed, the output of this:

```py
class Users(base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
[...]
```

was

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'users'
```

And I tried to fix the error by explicitly writing the database I'm refering to

```py
class Users(base):
    __tablename__ = "[homework-3-cc-database].users"
[...]
```

giving the output:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ']'.
```

I noticed that it inserted some square brackets, unwanted. Here is their SQL statement:

```sql
[SQL: SELECT TOP 1 [[homework-3-cc-database].users].user_id AS [[homework-3-cc-database].users_user_id] 
FROM [[homework-3-cc-database].users]]
```

This statement, ran from DataGrip works just fine:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 [homework-3-cc-schema].users.user_id 
FROM [homework-3-cc-schema].users
```

Do you have any suggestions regarding how should I fix this?

Comment: `homework-3-cc-database` is a schema name, not part of the table name.  Look at the sqlalchemy docs for how to specify the schema name.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277437/sqlalchemy-map-table-from-mssql-database-with-prefix-namespaces and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538132/sqlalchemy-declarative-schemas-in-sql-server-and-foreign-primary-keys

Comment: Thanks, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. I got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify the schema name in the following way:

```
__table_args__ = {"schema": "homework-3-cc-schema"}
```